# Find the difference for results from two select

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
table_1:  
A | B | C  
z | x | 12  
z | c | 13  
z | c | 10  
a | s | 14  
a | d | 11  

table_2:  
A | B | C  
z | c | 10  
z | x | 15  
z | x | 11  
a | d | 14  
a | s | 12
```

I want to:
- group the tables by A and B
- and find the difference for SUM of C for AB.

I started with:

```
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) from table_1 GROUP BY A, B;  
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) from table_2 GROUP BY A, B;
```

but I don't know how to JOIN them with adding additional column that is equal 
 to table_1.sum(C) - table_2.sum(c)

Expected result like:

```
A | B | sum1 | sum2 | diff  
z | x | 12   | 26   | -14 
z | c | 23   | 10   | 13
a | s | 14   | 12   | 2
a | d | 11   | 14   | -3
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well (having that table data.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join with subquery

```
select X.A,X.B, sum1, sum2, sum1-sum2 as diff from 
(
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) sum1
from table_1 GROUP BY A, B  
)X inner join
(
SELECT A, B, SUM(C) sum2
from table_2 GROUP BY A, B
)Y on X.A=Y.A and X.B=Y.B
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to happen when the groups are not the same in the two tables?  `inner join` can be dangerous because groups will disappear.

If you want to keep all groups, then one method is `union all`/`group by`:

```
select a, b, sum(c1) as sum1, sum(c2) as sum2,
       (sum(c2) - sum(c1)) as diff
from ((select a, b, c as c1, 0 as c2
       from table_1
      ) union all
      (select a, b, 0 as c1, c as c2
       from table_2
      )
     ) t
group by a, b
```